# Value Passed into ForEach says undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach

Im using the code below to try and find the first repeating character in a sequence. When I run the code in my browser, and stop it in the console at the letterArray.forEach function, console log error says my inputs to forEach are undefined. But it seems to me like forEach should just be taking the inputs from letterArray one at a time, seeing if they equal one, and return the result. Anybody know why it says my forEach loop cant read the inputs from my letterArray?

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(string) {

    var letterArray = [];
    letterArray['a'] = 0;
    letterArray['b'] = 0;
    letterArray['c'] = 0;
    letterArray['d'] = 0;
    letterArray['e'] = 0;
    letterArray['f'] = 0;
    letterArray['g'] = 0;
    letterArray['h'] = 0;
    letterArray['i'] = 0;
    letterArray['j'] = 0;
    letterArray['k'] = 0;
    letterArray['l'] = 0;
    letterArray['m'] = 0;
    letterArray['n'] = 0;
    letterArray['o'] = 0;
    letterArray['p'] = 0;
    letterArray['q'] = 0;
    letterArray['r'] = 0;
    letterArray['s'] = 0;
    letterArray['t'] = 0;
    letterArray['u'] = 0;
    letterArray['v'] = 0;
    letterArray['w'] = 0;
    letterArray['x'] = 0;
    letterArray['y'] = 0;
    letterArray['z'] = 0;
    for(var letter of string) {
      letterArray[letter] = letterArray[letter] + 1;
    }
    letterArray.forEach(function(value, index, thearay) {
      if (value == 1) {
        console.log(index);
      }
    });
}
var tester = "abacabad";
firstNotRepeatingCharacter(tester);
```

Comment: Can't have named keys for arrays.

Comment: I think you mean `var letter in string` rather than `of`.

Comment: You're trying to work with array like it's an object

Comment: @snapjs - yes, you can, but you shouldn't

Comment: @shadow - `for(var letter of string)` results in the letters in string. `for(var letter in string)` results in `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` - I think that part of the code is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal changes to your code required are as follows (see the comments `// ******` in the code)

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(string) {
    // *********** change to Object
    var letterArray = {};
    letterArray['a'] = 0;
    letterArray['b'] = 0;
    letterArray['c'] = 0;
    letterArray['d'] = 0;
    letterArray['e'] = 0;
    letterArray['f'] = 0;
    letterArray['g'] = 0;
    letterArray['h'] = 0;
    letterArray['i'] = 0;
    letterArray['j'] = 0;
    letterArray['k'] = 0;
    letterArray['l'] = 0;
    letterArray['m'] = 0;
    letterArray['n'] = 0;
    letterArray['o'] = 0;
    letterArray['p'] = 0;
    letterArray['q'] = 0;
    letterArray['r'] = 0;
    letterArray['s'] = 0;
    letterArray['t'] = 0;
    letterArray['u'] = 0;
    letterArray['v'] = 0;
    letterArray['w'] = 0;
    letterArray['x'] = 0;
    letterArray['y'] = 0;
    letterArray['z'] = 0;
    for(var letter of string) {
      letterArray[letter] = letterArray[letter] + 1;
    }
    // *********** an object has no forEach, 
    //             so, we now need to iterate through the keys 
    //             (a,b,c ...) of the object, 
    //             that's where Object.keys helps
    Object.keys(letterArray).forEach(function(key, index, thearay) {
        var value = letterArray[key]; //the value is letterArray[key]
        if (value == 1) {
            console.log(key);
        }
    });
}
var tester = "abacabad";
firstNotRepeatingCharacter(tester);
```

However, looking at the name of the function, I would expect

```
firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"); // c
firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abadacad"); // d
```

If so, the code would be far simpler

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string.split(string[i]).length == 2) {
            return string[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacadab"));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abadacab"));
```